# git clone from bare repository

Tags: windows, git

I created a Visual Studio project using git, later I created a remote bare repository in the path `\\xxx.yyy.com\dfs\CORP\Wkg\MoDat\tmp\avl\Repository\WCF\MIlib` and added it as origin in Visual Studio, then pushed.

Remote repository seems to be up to date, and from command line a `git remote -v` in the local folder returns these 2 lines

> origin \corp.repower.com\dfs\CORP\Wkg\MoDat\tmp\avl\Repository\WCF\MIlib (fetch)
>
> origin    \corp.repower.com\dfs\CORP\Wkg\MoDat\tmp\avl\Repository\WCF\MIlib (push)

I assume I can clone to another local folder from the remote path, so I just copied and pasted exactly the line above to clone it elsewhere

```
git clone "\\xxx.yyy.com\dfs\CORP\Wkg\MoDat\tmp\avl\Repository\WCF\MIlib" .
```

Now I get an error

> git : Cloning into '.'...
>
> fatal: '\xxx.yyy.com\dfs\CORP\Wkg\MoDat\tmp\avl\Repository\WCF\MIlib' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I am cloning in the same system in another folder using the same (administrator) user, so it's definitly not relate to access right.

I see in the error that a `\` is missing, am I doing something wrong? should the path be somehow escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you writing these commands in some kind of bash?

When I was working on Windows I always used forward slashes `/` instead of backslashes. See if it works for you.